# Inconsistent behavior of web driver with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, webdriver

Inconsistent behavior of web driver with IE9

When I try to run the 7-10 tests sequentially then 3 out of 5 times some test fails indicating that some element not found.
however I have put explicit wait wherever necessary Interesting it works in 2 occasions. I am using IESERVER - 64 bit to run the tests.

Below are the details of my configuration:

1. Java version - jdk-7u7-windows-x64
2. Eclipse version -64 bit eclipse  - Kepler
3. Testng version - 6.8.0
4. Selenium web driver - 2.28.0
5. IE driver.exe (64 bit)
6. IE9 & WIN7

However These tests were working fine for win XP & IE8 with IE driver.exe ( 32 bit).behavior of the scripts was consistent.

Can anybody suggest any pointers?

Note - I have set the following
•   For IE9 – protected mode is on for all security settings.

Comment: Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.28.0.0
Listening on port 12333
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='edpsFileValidations']/font (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=internet explorer, nativeEvents=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=9}]

Comment: This problem seems to have been resolved.

below the details of it:

1. Instead of “driver. Close” used “driver. Quit” because when using iedriverserver.exe it crates multiple instances of it in the Processes (windows task manager) and it’s not closed.

2. Used before and after test method for log in and log out so processing was fast.

3. Used explicit wait with optimum time.
Requesting all of you to post the answers once the issues are resolved so that other people can benefit from it because most of the times its observed that there are no reply if the problems is solved.